# User's last login time?

Tags: box-api, boxapiv2

I'd like to know when a given user last logged in.  It seems that the User object doesn't include this information (creation and modification only).  Should I look to leverage the Events API (seems inefficient) or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, look to the [Events](https://box-content.readme.io/#events) API for this. Specifically, you'll want to use the [Enterprise Events](https://box-content.readme.io/#get-events-in-an-enterprise) API and query for events of the type `LOGIN`. This requires an access token with administrative privileges.

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/events?stream_type=admin_logs&event_type=LOGIN \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Note that:

- The returned events are paged, so you may need to adjust the page size or execute multiple queries to find the event(s) you're looking for.
- You can use the `created_after` and `created_before` query parameters to limit the returned events to a specific time period.
- You can also look for `FAILED_LOGIN` events: `event_type=LOGIN,FAILED_LOGIN`

Comment: Hmm... seeing as I'm trying to build a list of login times for all of my users (3000+) -- many of which who have _never_ logged in before, I'm not sure this is going to scale.  Just takes far too long to run... perhaps need to ask Box to extend the API.  I know they can send me a list of all of my users with last login times intact (when I request via my customer rep), so obviously this is stored somewhere they can get to quickly.

Comment: Does increasing the page size help at all? You can also issue parallel, time-sliced requests using the created_before/created_after fields.